# How to implement server.on() without any libraries?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, esp32, web-server

I was trying to setup a web server with Arduino and ESP32, without using the ESP32 libraries.
Currently I'm able to display a webpage(a form with single submit button) from the server, with only using AT commands.

But how can I receive GET/POST requests send buy the form fields?

In the [WebServer.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h) library this is done by the method

```
    server.on("/actionPage", HTTP_GET, []() {
        server.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
        server.send(200, "text/html", "This is actionPage");
    })
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without libraries, I searched a lot, but didn't found a solution for this..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why, in gods name, would you choose to cripple an ESP32 with AT commands? You are currently using a Fiat Panda to tow a Lamborghini, in which you have placed a toddler to control it. Crazy, man...

Comment: @Majenko, it may be crazy, but is it doable?

Comment: Sure, it's doable. You just need to send the right AT commands to perform the task you need to do. Personally I wouldn't, but you do you m8.

Comment: @Majenko, I was just studying how the AT commands are used to configure a web server, and there are a lot of examples are available showing how to send GET/POST request from a local server to the ESP, But didn't found one regarding  how to receive GET/POST request from a client!!

Comment: just curious about how these things are done with AT commands..Even didn't know where these AT commands are stored in arduino libraries. It would be extremely helpful if you guys could give me any information regarding this, Thanks!

Comment: Until you raised the question, I didn't even know there was AT firmware for the ESP32. I have no idea how they chose to implement it. What does the manual for the AT firmware say?